# How to use function on every element by class name?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Now I am using "Perfect Scroller" which is a custom scroll bar plugin.

I followed the Document to setup.[Here](https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar)

I use code like below and every was good.

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
Ps.initialize(container);
```

However, I want to use it by "ClassName" not by "ID" because there are lots of areas.

I know I can use

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('selected_area')[0];
```

But this is only one element.

My question is how to do it by ClassName?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do in a loop:

```
 var container = document.getElementsByClassName('selected_area');
 for(var i in container) {
      Ps.initialize(container[i]);
 }
```

This iterates all containers and initialize it independently.

Comment: No, its a key which happens to be the index in this special case. And because of this you should not use `for ... in ...` as it is meant to iterate over the enumerable keys of an object. Use a `for` loop instead.

Comment: Interesting reading: http://www.etnassoft.com/2011/09/21/analizando-el-bucle-for-in-en-javascript/ `for-in` is better if you don't use it in a customized array, but in a structure of things like `getElementByClassName` returns is totally accepted and good practice. You doesn't need iterate in numeric order this initialization. All of you goes post by post with a new mantra `Don't use for-in`, and it is not correct. Please, understand how for-in works and then use when you need it.

Answer (score 1):

```
var container = document.getElementsByClassName('selected_area');

for(var i = 0; i < container.size; i++){
     Ps.initialize(container[i]);
}
```

Although I haven't had a look at this plugin you are using, so I don't know if it should be initialised more than once. Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

you can also use:

```
var container = document.querySelectorAll('.selected_area');
```

---

furthermore you can transform it to an array(it's only necessary if you want to use standard array methods)

```
 var contArr = [].slice.call(container)
```

in this case you can then use it with `forEach`

```
 contArr.forEach(function(x){Ps.initialize(x)}
```